# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(x).style')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, typeerror

**What I want my javascript to do:**

I have a div that contains a "***onmouseover='getPosition(x)'***" that is added and could also be removed in my javascript when I press a certain button. The function '*getPosition()*' always runs while the div is not yet deleted so that it will always get and update the position of the div and display it's x and y position in a ***textfield placeholder***

```
$("#canvas").append('<div onmouseover="getPosition(this.id);"style="top:'+initXYpos+'px; left:'+initXYpos+'px;">Button '+index+'</div>');
```

**The Problem:**

When I delete the div that holds "***getPosition(this.id)***", it still runs the function while it gives an error:
 "***TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(x).style')***"

I just want it to stop running when I delete the div.

**This is the function for getPosition(x):**

```
function getPosition(x){   
    $('#canvas_container').mouseover(function(){
    timer =  setInterval(function() {
      var xPos = document.getElementById(x).style.left;
      var yPos = document.getElementById(x).style.top;
      document.getElementById(x+'_fieldX').placeholder = xPos;
      document.getElementById(x+'_fieldY').placeholder = yPos;
    }, 10); }
```

---

**Note:**

*I'm sorry if you think my question is caused by a stupid mistake. I'm really new to Javascript, I hope you understand and be happy to help me out.*

Comment: Take a look at `unbind()` http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: why do you have this `$('#canvas_container').mouseover(function(){` inside your getPosition function

Comment: you want `clearInterval(timer)`, it never stop to run until a clear

Comment: The function keep running because of the interval, so the cleverest I can currently think is **clearing** the interval (timer) and **unbinding** the mouseover event, because if you only remove the event listener the timer interval will in any case run forever, unless you clear it. Any chance to get a demo fiddle to further help you?

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript, when you remove the div, you must also stop the timer using this line of code:

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

***My suggestion will be to remove the timer because you do not really need it to achieve what you want to do***